# <img src='img.png'> not showing local file (react)

Tags: javascript, html, css, linux, reactjs

I have an img tag in javascript that is not showing the file (local file).
The file is in a folder called images and the js file I'm trying to use the image is in a folder called Pages. both folders are in the same directory.

[image: file structure]

```html
<img src='../images/img.png' alt='template'/>
```

This is the way im using the tag and the browser is showing the alt name with the icon on an invalid image

Comment: Can you share your full file structure?  Perhaps the relative path is incorrect.

Comment: @dkershaw made an edit with it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use relative path when the image is in the `public` folder of your app, whatever is better to pass image through webpack, so that way you just need to import the image as a normal object and use it into your component.

```
import template from '../images/image.jpg/

// later ir your code 

<img src={template} alt="image al" />
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to import the image in react component like the following.

```
import image from '../images/img.png';
```

and use in the img tag like the following

```
<img src={image} />
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a React project you need to require the image in your `src` like this:

```
src={ require('../images/img.png') }
```